# How can I exchange a set of coins with different currencies into USD or gift cards in the US?

Tags: usa, money, california

I have a stack of coins that have different currencies. 
Where can I conveniently convert them into USD or (less preferable) gift cards? Ideally, I would like 1) not to have to sort them 2) avoid fees or unfavorable exchange rates.

Coinstar machines don't work with foreign currencies.  [What types of coins will a Coinstar machine accept?](https://www.fuzeqna.com/orangecountys/ext/kb1474-coin-coinstar-what-type-change-process-machine-voucher-star-nickel-dime-quarter-penny-dollar-what)
  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170927002456/https://www.fuzeqna.com/orangecountys/ext/kb1474-coin-coinstar-what-type-change-process-machine-voucher-star-nickel-dime-quarter-penny-dollar-what))

I live in California.

Comment: Related: *[How do I get money back for my foreign coins?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1786)* and *[Where can I exchange British coins when travelling from Dublin to Los Angeles?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100309)* It is nearly impossible to exchange foreign pocket change for American currency within the U.S.; bureaux might make an exception if we are talking about hundreds of dollars worth. The standard advice is to donate, exchange with tourists heading overseas, or sell to collectors.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I wonder how Unicef sorts the coins by currency. One difference with the two linked questions is that in my case coins are unsorted (it's unclear in [How do I get money back for my foreign coins?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1786/1810) if coins are sorted). Maybe some of my coins are worth melting, that'd be a good start.

Comment: Head to an international airport and walk up to the currency exchange counter.  Although, depending on how much you have it might not be worth it.